# Class or not in Page Scraper (Python BeautifulSoup)

Tags: python, python-3.x, classes, beautifulsoup

I am trying to figure out whether the below is better than just having a raw script or just a script with functions.

```
class WebsiteImages(object):
    
    def __init__(self,photographer,Website_url):
        self.photographer = photographer
        self.Website_url = Website_url
        
    def GetNumberOfResultPages(self):
        #Get the exact number of pages in the results
        from selenium import webdriver
        browser = webdriver.Firefox()
        browser.get(self.Website_url) 
        last_number_page = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[@class='search-pagination__last-page']") 
        for i in last_number_page:
            number_of_pages = i.text
        return number_of_pages

    def GetImageIds(self):
        number_of_pages = self.GetNumberOfResultPages()
        Website_ids = []
        self.number_of_pages = number_of_pages
        #For each page get the image IDs
        import urllib
        from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
        import sys
        from time import sleep
        for page in range(1,int(number_of_pages)+1):
            #Extract the image id only and save it in file
            url = urllib.request.urlopen(self.Website_url+'&page='+str(page)+'&sort=best')
            sleep(1)
            content = url.read()
            soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'lxml')
            #search on page for div class and extract the id between the gi-asset attribute
            images_found = soup.find_all('gi-asset') #gi-asset is the HTML object that contains the image and the id in the search results
            for i in range(len(images_found)):  #range(len(images_found))
                Website_id = images_found[i].get('data-asset-id') #data-asset-id' is the HTML object that contains the ID
                if Website_id not in 'placeholder':
                    Website_ids.append(Website_id)
        return Website_ids

# Define some photographers
john_smith = WebsiteImages('John%20Smith', 'https://www.WebsiteImages.co.uk/search/photographer?assettype=image&photographer=John%20smith')

# Now we can get to the image IDs easily
#print(john_smith.GetNumberOfResultPages())
print(john_smith.GetImageIds())
```

The idea of using the class was to make the script more organised and the outputs accessible for different search results. Example below:

```
one_guy = WebsiteImages('One%20Guy', 'https://www.WebsiteImages.co.uk/search/photographer?photographer=John%20smith')

two_guy = WebsiteImages('Two%20Guy', 'https://www.WebsiteImages.co.uk/search/photographer?photographer=John%20smith')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Class inheritance

Classes no longer have to be subclasses from object

```
class WebsiteImages:
```

## Naming Conventions

Methods and variable names should be `snake_case`. Classes should be `PascalCase`, so you got that correct :-).

## Imports

Any and all imports should go at the top of the file.

## `f""` strings

You should use `f""` strings to directly implement variables into your strings.

```
url = urllib.request.urlopen(f"{self.website_url}&page={page}&sort=best")
```

## User Interaction

The way a user has to interact with this program is pretty challenging to understand. If I was a normal user, I would do something like this:

```
person = WebsiteImages("John Smith", "https://www.WebsiteImages.co.uk")
```

But I would get an error, or no images returned because I didn't know the name had to be encoded with `%20` and I didn't know I needed to specify a very particular url. I would blame it on the program and look for something else that's more user friendly.

---

I would solve this by only requiring a name. Since you're going to one website, you can save the url as an instance variable and sort things out there, instead of relying on a user to provide perfect input. *Never trust user input*.

```
john = WebsiteImages("John Smith")
print(john.get_image_ids())
```

And within the constructor you can do something like this:

```
def __init__(self, photographer: str):
    self.photographer = '%20'.join(photographer.split())
    self.website_url = f"https://www.WebsiteImages.co.uk/search/photographer?photographer={self.photographer}"
```

Comment: Just one comment. No need to join the '%20' bit as it is an HTML unicode and it is automatically generated in the link if it is blank :)